# How to create a new channel with Faye, and then access it via a url or model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, faye

I'm using [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) based on [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails/) to create a chat message system. The only thing is, I want different channels "chatrooms" that users can subscribe to by visiting their url. Also, I want to represent each channel with a model, so that I can find them by name or index. How do I do this? For some reason, I can't find any good resources on this. By the way, I'm not terribly new to Rails, I just don't know how to use Faye at all.

Here's my use case, just to be clear:

> User visits my site.
>
> User enters "chat1" into a form, which lets say accesses
> the Chatrooms controller, index action
>
> Controller finds all Chatrooms by name "chat1"
>
> If it can't find it, it instantiates a new chatroom called "chat1" and subscribes the user to it
>
> Redirects user to that chatroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faye seems to automatically create new channels when you ask to subscribe to them. In your javascript, instead of subscribing to "foo" for example, do this:

```
var channel_name = "/chatrooms/"+"<%= @chatroom.id %>";
    // Subscribe to the public channel
    var public_subscription = client.subscribe(channel_name, function(data) {
      $('<p></p>').html(data.username + ": " + data.msg).appendTo('#blab_box');
     });
```